# calculate TOTAL CONSUMPTION and Consumption per person

Tags: javascript

I try to calculate calculate TOTAL Consumption and Consumption per person.

Relevant code :

```
$(function () {
    $(".items").keyup(function (event) {
        var total = 0;
        $(".items").each(function () {
            var gtotal = 0;
            $(this).find(".targetfields").each(function () {
           var qty = parseInt($(this).find(".quantity").val()||'0');
           var rate = parseInt($(this).find(".rate").val()||'0');
                var subtotal = qty * rate;
                $(this).find(".subtotal").val(subtotal);
                if (!isNaN(subtotal)) gtotal += subtotal;

            });
            $(this).find(".g_total").html(gtotal + "Din");
            total += gtotal;
        });
        $("#total").html(total + "Din");
    });

});
```

A fiddle for the tests : http://jsfiddle.net/Odisej/CgeHU/

I get stuck...What's wrong in this script?

Comment: Don't just link to a fiddle : put the relevant code in your question.

Comment: i would highly recomment you to stop saving data in the dom

Comment: Thanks.I figure your recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parseInt('')` gives `NaN`. And when you multiply `NaN` by a number, you get `NaN`.

So I'd suggest to remplace

```
            var qty = parseInt($(this).find(".quantity").val());
            var rate = parseInt($(this).find(".rate").val());
```

with

```
            var qty = parseInt($(this).find(".quantity").val())||0;
            var rate = parseInt($(this).find(".rate").val())||0;
```

Comment: Wow thanks! That is work and it's eliminated NaN.

Comment: I am new to javascript and I made it through on-line tutorials.
I need to calculate Consumption per person and Washing Machine - normal program form to complet script.